# Typescript Conditional Return Types Properly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am pondering if there is a "better" way to type functions in which the return type depends conditionally on the type of the arguments.

Let me examplify:

Let's say we have these types:

```
type TPerson = {
   name: string,
   petId: `cat_${number}` | `dog_${number}`,
   ...
}

type TCat = {
  id: `cat_${number}`,
  name: string,
  ...
}

type TDog = {
  id: `dog_${number}`,
  name: string,
  ...
}
```

(I'm sorry for all of the non cats neither dogs not represented here)

I want to create a function that takes an array of "persons" and an array of pets (cats or dogs) and a string, either "cat" or "dog", and then returns to me the list of either cats or dogs which are part of the pets of all those people. Like this:

```
type TPet = TCat | TDog;

function getPets(people: Array<Tperson>, pets: Array<TPet>, type: "cat" | "dog") {
   let result = [];
   people.forEach((person)=>{
     const typeOfPet = person.petId.split("_")[0] //<--either "cat" or "dog"
     if(typeOfPet === type){
        const foundPet = pets.find((pet)=>pet.id === person.petId;
        result.push(foundPet);
     }
   })
   return result; //<--I need this to be uniquely Array<TDog> or Array<TCat>
}
```

Now what I want is for this function return type to automatically be Array if I pass the type "cat" to its argument, and the same for dogs.

A working solution is to use generenics with a union type fot the pet types, and ternary operators explicity defining the return type of the function, like this:

```
type TPetKind = "cat"|"dog"

function getPets<T extends TPetKind>(people: Array<Tperson>, pets: Array<TPet>, type: T):(T extends "cat" ? Array<TCat> : T extends "dog" ? Array<TDog> : never) {
 ....
```

But this seems... lets say its not beautiful and makes us think about not using typescript.

So my question is:

***Is there another way to type this in a more concise, short, elegant and scalable manner?***

(lets say I want to add iguanas and fish and bird and so on in the future, and I dont want to keep messing with the return type of the function or adding ternary operators)

Minimal reproducible example:

```
type TPerson = {
   name: string,
   petId: `cat_${number}` | `dog_${number}`,
   
}

type TCat = {
  id: `cat_${number}`,
  name: string,
}

type TDog = {
  id: `dog_${number}`,
  name: string, 
}

type TPet = TCat | TDog;

type TPetKind = "cat"|"dog"

function getPets<T extends TPetKind>(people: Array<TPerson>, pets: Array<TPet>, type: T):(T extends "cat" ? Array<TCat> : T extends "dog" ? Array<TDog> : never) {
   let result: (TPet|undefined)[] = [];
   people.forEach((person)=>{
     const typeOfPet = person.petId.split("_")[0] //<--either "cat" or "dog"
     if(typeOfPet === type){
        const foundPet = pets.find((pet)=>pet.id === person.petId;
        result.push(foundPet);
     }
   })
   return result as any; //<--I need this to be uniquely Array<TDog> or Array<TCat>
}

const folks = [{name: "Ana", petId: "cat_420"}, {name: "John", petId: "cat_69"}, {name: "Julia", petId: "dog_50135"}] as Array<TPerson>;

const allPets = [{id: "dog_101", name: "Jhonathan"},{id: "cat_420", name: "Mary Jane"},{id: "cat_69", name: "Ana"},{id: "dog_666", name: "Mephisto"},{id: "dog_50135", name: "Bob"}] as Array<TPet>;

const catsWithOwners = getPets(folks, allPets, "cat");
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code to provide a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Right now I get a slew of errors unrelated to your question due to undeclared types and values.  I suggest you test the code in a standalone IDE (like the TypeScript playground), fix any problems that distract from your question, and then paste the result back here as plaintext.

Comment: Hey @jcalz thanks for the response. I think I was not very clear. The point is not this particular code, its working fine as it is with no problems at all, my question is if there exists a better way to type this kind of pattern. I will rewrite my question entirely to treat this issue in a more objective way.

Comment: Please make sure that your code is a [mre]; I suggest you test it in a standalone IDE and fix any problems you're not asking about.  Pseudocode and typos only make it harder for others to help you.

Comment:  I guess you won't test your code in an IDE?  `function <T extends TPetKind>getPets` is not how TS works and `Tperson` isn't the name of your type.   etc.   I'm going to unsubscribe from edit updates here and check back one more time sometime later today.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, you are right, since this is a theoretical rather than a debugging question, I've seen no point on copying or testing the code, since theres nothing to test. But I guess I'll correct it if you want to put this on an IDE.